# How do I make a label keep switching between two colors in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am trying to make my label flash two colors on repeat. I want it to continuously repeat the text color Blue and Black. Is this possible? And can someone help me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `NSTimer` and below is complete code for that:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    var timer : NSTimer?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    var textColorIsBlue = false
    func update() {
        if !textColorIsBlue {
            lbl.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        } else {
            lbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }

        textColorIsBlue = !textColorIsBlue
    }
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

And you can modify timer as per your need.

And whenever you don't need time you can stop it by using `timer?.invalidate()`.

Comment: You've got a memory leak on the timer, since you don't keep a reference to it, you can't invalidate it.  The run-loop keeps a strong reference to the timer until you invalidate lt. Also, you really should set the `tolerance` of the timer to improved system performance.

Comment: Updated my answer.. :) @Abizern

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help but create an alternative example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var label: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            label.text = "This is just some sample text"
        }
    }
    private var timer: dispatch_source_t?
    private var generator: AlternatingColorGenerator?

    deinit {
        guard let timer = timer else { return }
        dispatch_source_cancel(timer)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        generator = AlternatingColorGenerator(colors: [.redColor(), .blueColor(), .greenColor()])

        let t = repeatingTimer(1, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] () -> Void in
            self?.label.textColor = self?.generator?.next()
        }

        dispatch_resume(t)
        timer = t

        label.textColor = generator?.next()
    }


}

private class AlternatingColorGenerator: GeneratorType {
    var currentIndex: Int = 0
    let numberOfColors: Int
    let colors: [UIColor]

    init(colors: [UIColor]) {
        self.colors = colors
        numberOfColors = colors.count
    }

    func next() -> UIColor? {
        let color = colors[currentIndex]

        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % numberOfColors

        return color
    }
}

private func repeatingTimer(interval: NSTimeInterval, queue: dispatch_queue_t, action: () -> Void) -> dispatch_source_t {
    let timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue)
    let timerInterval = UInt64(interval) * NSEC_PER_SEC
    let timerLeeway = timerInterval / 10

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, action)
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timerInterval, timerLeeway)

    return timer
}
```

[image]

This uses a GCD timer, rather than an NSTimer, and rather than toggle the colours with a method, I've created a generator.

This uses a different programming style: one where the generation of things (timers and colours to use) is separated from the place where they are consumed.